# How to remove tag style from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i remove the style="" from the html inside data variable?

```
function printCalendar($scope) {
    $scope.print = function(){
        var data = $('.fc-content').html();
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', '');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/printcalendar.css"/></head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.document.close();
        mywindow.focus();
        mywindow.print();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this by *cloning* `fc-content` - that way you can use jQuery to perform the manipulation:

```
var $clone = $('.fc-content').clone(); // Clone the element
$clone.find("[style]") // Find the elements with style attributes
    .removeAttr("style") // Remove the attribute entirely
var data = .html(); // Now grab the clone's HTML
```